# Obtaining the value of an option in a picklist

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating a phony instance of an entity `beep`. It has a required field of type `picklist` called `pickaboo`. First I omitted it but then the application started to lament throwing error messages at me due to some business logic demanding all the newly created instances of `beep` to have that field assigned.

```
Entity entity = new Entity { LogicalName = "beep" };
Guid guid = proxy.Create(entity);
proxy.Delete("beep", guid);
```

I don't give a rodent's tail section about that demand because right after I've created the instance, I'm removing it. However CRM gives a huge rodent and doesn't let me do my magic. So, I went clever and added an attribute for the missing attribute.

```
OptionSetValue option = new OptionSetValue(0);
Entity entity = new Entity { LogicalName = "beep" };
entity.Attributes.Add("pickaboo", option);
Guid guid = proxy.Create(entity);
proxy.Delete("beep", guid);
```

Of course, it didn't work because zero isn't a valid value. Apparently, CRM adds a hash number based on the solution so the actual "zero" has the numeric value like "846000000000", the actual "one" has "846000000001" etc.

How can I obtain that value programmatically?

*Right now I have an ugly workaround obtaining **all the `beep`s** and getting the value from the first of them. Don't even get me started on how much sleep I'm loosing knowing how embarrassing it looks, would anybody take time to give me some feed-back. :(*

Answer (score 3):

You've got two options.

1. You can use the CrmSrvcUtil to generate your OptionSetValues as enums...  This would create a pickaboo enum that you could then reference in your code
   `entity.Attributes.Add("pickaboo", new OptionSetValue((int)pickaboo.YourEnumValue);`
2. You could also use the `RetrieveOptionSetRequest` message to get a list of all values for the particular option set you're interested in. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470498/retrieve-optionsets-in-dynamics-2011)

Comment: This particular customer won't let me log in without supervision. I think running anything in the console would cause a cardiac arrest, hehe. I'll give option 2 a swing and hope that it'll resolve my little issue. Thanks, buddy, especially if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Since I know that *all* CRM programmers are lazy pigs (own experience, haha), I know that you'd prefer a short and comprehensive solution. I realize that you're looking for a quick access to **just a single valid value**. If I'm mistaken, stop reading - use the suggestion of @Daryl - he's got a good answer for ya.

If I'm right, though, use this code to get the first valid option value (provided it exists). Just in case, remember to surround it with `try/catch` so if you misspell or such, you won't end up scratching your head.

```
RetrieveAttributeRequest request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
{
  EntityLogicalName = "beep",
  LogicalName = "pickaboo",
  RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};
RetrieveAttributeResponse response 
  = proxy.Execute(request) as RetrieveAttributeResponse;
PicklistAttributeMetadata metaData 
  = response.AttributeMetadata as PicklistAttributeMetadata;
OptionSetValue option 
  = new OptionSetValue(metaData.OptionSet.Options[0].Value ?? -1);
```

1. NB - I'm assuming that you've got a working connection via a proxy called `proxy`.
2. Set a `try/catch` around the whole code, just in case out of bound exception occurs.
3. Make sure to handle the option of `-1`, since `Value` returned is a nullable integer.

Answer (score 1):

This question has inspired me to blog.

If you have a look at my post below its got a function that can be used to find the int values of picklists (global and local optionsets), statecode, statuscode and the boolean (two option) fields.

[CRM 2011 Programatically Finding the Values of Picklists, Optionsets, Statecode, Statuscode and Boolean (Two Options)](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/crm-2011-programatically-finding-the-values-of-picklists-optionsets-statecode-statuscode-and-boolean-two-options/)

Comment: Darn - my boss is actually nagging that I should blog more and I was going to write an article on this subject, just like you did. Now, it'll feel like a knock-off. But I'm going to do that anyway. Need to keep boss happy...